# Maxwell equations in curved spacetime with cosmological constant

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, maxwell-equations, cosmological-constant

I am aware of Maxwell Equations in Curved Spacetime. But how do these equations change if the cosmological constant is not assumed to vanish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a cosmological constant $\Lambda$ won't change Maxwell's equations (which are obtained when you vary the action with respect to the field $A_\mu$), but it will change the equations of motion in the gravity sector. See [Supersymmetric, cold and lukewarm black holes in cosmological Einstein-Maxwell theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9203018v1), for instance.

Also this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#Einstein%E2%80%93Maxwell_equations) article.

Comment: The metric appears in Maxwell’s equations, and the cosmological constant helps determine the metric.

Comment: @G.Smith Right. But we're talking at the level of the equations of motion, not solutions of it. These are 2 very different things.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. The metric appears in the equations, and therefore you get different solutions for different metrics.

Comment: @G.Smith I believe Avantgarde means that, indeed, the solutions are different for different metrics; but the form of the equation itself (i.e., $dA=d^\dagger A=0$) is the same, whether you turn on $\Lambda$ or not.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes, but that because the form of those equations has obscured the presence of the metric. When you solve Maxwell’s equations in curved spacetime, the metric matters.

Comment: The cosmological constant $\Lambda$ isn't describing a *charged fluid*, so why should it be included into the Maxwell equations?

Comment: I did not say that the cosmological constant appears in Maxwell’s equations. I said that the *metric* appears in Maxwell’s equations, and the cosmological constant affects the metric. I am not asserting that the answer is wrong, and I have not downvoted it. I am asserting that it leaves the OP with a misleading impression that a cosmological constant would have no effect on electromagnetism (such as on cosmological-scale electromagnetic fields, if they existed). It *would*.

Comment: @G.Smith, I agree with you: the cosmological constant is determining (in part) the metric from Einstein equation, so will have an indirect effect on the Maxwell field propagating in that spacetime.

Comment: The OP should realize that the metric affects EM fields, and EM fields affect the metric. If you want to take the latter into account, you have to solve Maxwell’s equations *and* the Einstein field equations as a set of *simultaneous* partial differential equations. An example of this is a Reissner-Nordstorm or a Kerr-Newman black hole. Charged black holes would have different EM fields from these solutions if there is a cosmological constant.

Comment: @G.Smith *The metric appears in Maxwell’s equations* that is not strictly true. If one tries to minimize the appearances of metric in EM field equations, then only volume form is needed. A concrete realization of this line of thinking is “premetric electrodynamics” of Hehl & Obukhov (see eg [physics/0610221](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0610221) for overview and links).